# FLEX PLM with integration of Windchill

Tags: apache-flex, ptc-windchill

Do any one know what is FLEX PLM with integration of Windchill..

I need to learn it quickly becuase this will be implementing in one of our project.What is the programming language used in this? i have zero knowledge about this.

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: You tagged this question "Adobe Flex"; but I can honestly say I don't know what PLM or Windchill are so cannot answer your question.  Is this question correctly tagged?  If so; you may consider adding more information.

Answer (score 2):

FlexPLM is a Product Lifecycle Management solution from PTC that addresses the need of the footwear and apparel industry.  This solution is build on Windchill, which is a j2ee application .  For more information on FlexPLM, see [PTC University Learning Exchange](http://learningexchange.ptc.com/tutorials/by_sub_product/sub_product_id:6)

Hope this helps,

Ricardo.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no support for direct integration of CAD software in a manner similar to Creo/Windchill integration or FlexPLM AI integration
Supports associated/reference document for library objects
Supports CAD data into Product Specification**

*Both are PLM Products you can Integrate ALM with PLM.*

Eg. ALM Integrity Lifecycle Manager with PTC Windchill

If you want to do here is [youtube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayfXILRUkZ4)